# Когда надо создавать активити и когда надо использовать фрагменты?

Tags: android

Когда надо создавать активити и когда надо использовать фрагменты?

**Пример приложения:**

У меня будет карта с определениям место положения, перед этим я хочу сделать загрузочный экран пока карта погрузиться. После того как определиться адрес будет кнопка для оформления заказа (для этого будет форма). Затем можно будет видеть где передвигаеться машина с заказам. Также будет окно регистрации если пользователь не зарегистрирован.

Как это все правильно организовать? Какой принцип построения окно должен быть?

Хочу использовать Navigation Drawer Activity и не могу понять это надо создавать новый активити и около 5 xml файлов для каждого окна (настройки, форма заказа, регистрация, карта и т.д) или создать один активити на 10 окон и пытаться засунуть все в фрагмент.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что и как использовать выбирает программист в зависимости от задачи. Сделать приложение подобное вашему можно как из нескольких activity так и из одной activity и нескольких фрагментов.

Activity это сущность представляющая экран приложения. Их может быть несколько, и они могут меняться, передавать между собой данные. Экран приложения может содержать несколько типовых элементов (как пазл) и вот эти элементы удобнее сделать на основе фрагментов. На телефоне фрагмент может занимать весь экран, на планшете на экране может оказаться несколько фрагментов, что дает гибкость интерфейса.

Фрагменты по использованию ресурсов и удобству работы проще и легче activity. И по моему опыту организовывать навигацию и смену экранов с помощью фрагментов гораздо удобнее. При такой модели activity является контейнером, в котором отображаются и меняются несколько фрагментов.

Фрагменты не взаимодействуют друг с другом. Все взаимодействие осуществляется через activity. Механизмы взаимодействия могут быть разными. Лично мне удобнее обустраивать взаимодействие через интерфейсы. У меня обычно все механизмы взаимодействия прописываются как protected в наследованном от Fragment классе (можно назвать его BaseFragment или MyFragment или еще как-нибуть) и все остальные фрагменты приложения наследуются уже от него и используют эти механизмы взаимодействия как свои собственные без дублирования кода.

Отдельно стоит отметить, что существуют также другие точки зрения относительно Activity и фрагментов. Есть статьи в которых людей призывают использовать фрагменты как можно реже. Надо просто попробовать и то и другое и понять что удобнее лично для вас.

P.S. И я таки рекомендую прочитать вот это: [Фрагменты](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/components/fragments.html#Design)

Comment: а почему советуют использовать фрагменты реже, или можно ссылочку,интересно!

Comment: Пошел ссылочку доставать и не нашел. Насколько я помню в тех статьях упирали на сложность работы с backstack и что лучше использовать виджеты-презентеры для которых писать свой backstack самостоятельно. Я сделал вывод, что люди просто не умеют их (фрагменты) готовить. В ранних версиях фрагментов действительно было куча проблем, по последняя версия библиотеки support в части фрагментов достаточно стабильно работает.

Answer (score 0):

Соглашусь с мнением автора из ответа выше, что программист сам должен определить этот самый баланс между использованием активити и фрагментов.

Использование активити без фрагментов в каком то смысле может быть проще т.к. элементы которые находятся в активити могут общаться с активити и другими элементами в нем - напрямую, с другой стороны - ничто не мешает вам использовать Callback'и для общения фрагментов с активити, что в свою очередь может сделать ваш код универсальней.

Так же выбор может зависеть от задачи. Например, есть активити в котором есть 4-е tab'ы - их есть смысл сделать фрагментами, так как они в процессе использования могут неоднократно переиспользоватся, при потребности можно написать интерфейсы для общения с активити  и таким образом вы можете получить независимые элементы которые могут общаться между собой и могут потом использоваться где то еще, т.к. они не завязаны на одном конкретном активити.